# LINQ To Return Properties from a class

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml, uwp-xaml

First off, New to XAML and Programming in general. I am trying to populate a XAML Datagrid in the .cs file.

I have classes for each SQL table I'm using, holding properties that reference columns

```cs
    public partial class TTDepartment
    {
        public TTDepartment()
        {
            this.TTEventLogs = new HashSet<TTEventLog>();
            this.TTUserDepartments = new HashSet<TTUserDepartment>();
        }

        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Manager { get; set; }
        public string ManagerEmail { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TTEventLog> TTEventLogs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TTUserDepartment> TTUserDepartments { get; set; }
    }
```

What I am doing currently is attempting to use LINQ queries on my classes to retrieve data, Like this

(I'm Aware there is likely a better way to do this) please help

```
        private void GetDepartments()
        {

            using (var context = new CetusEntities())// New instance of Database class
            {
                var linqDept = context.TTDepartments.Where(s => s.Department != "" || s.Department != null); // Should return All Departments from TTDepartments Class?
                //Populate colDept in Datagrid with results from LINQ
            } 
        }
```

Here is the XAML for Datagrid

```
                <DataGrid x:Name="dgDept"  Height="200">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colDept" Binding="{Binding Source = {StaticResource Department}}" Header="Department"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colMan" Binding="{Binding Source = {StaticResource Department}}" Header="Manager"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Email"></DataGridTextColumn>-->
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Is this not working or what? What do you mean by better ways?

Comment: var linqDept is not returning the properties I want to acess

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: I tested your LINQ queries and found it still return the Department which is empty or null, do you have the same issue? If you use `var linqDept = TTDepartments.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Department));` this method to exclude the Department property with empty or null value, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
var linqDept = context.TTDepartments.Where(s =>(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

Also, verify that you actually have data in your db. Then *debug*.

//set the datagrid source to test.

```
dtGrid.ItemsSource = linqDept;
```

XAML Example:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colDept" Binding="{Binding Department}" Header="Department"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Okay need to rephrase, Question wasnt asked the best. It doesnt matter if the results are null or not, I simply want to return the entire column Departments from my SQL Table(There is no nulls)... != was just the logic I though of using to achieve this. Hence I say there must be a better way to acess TTDepartment.Department with a LINQ. Thanks for your time